# c++ how print how many element are repeated in 2 array?

Tags: c++, arrays, count

I have two arrays and I want to count how many elements are same between two arrays.
I try many times but the output is not correct. The correct should be `6` times
but the output is `4` times in the code.

Note: if `s1` is `"ss"` and `s2` is `"ss"`, is the result `2`

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char s1[] = "FOOBART";
    char s2[] = "BFORATO";
    int flag=0;

    for(int i=0, j=0; i < sizeof(s1) && j < sizeof(s2); ) {
        if(s1[i] == s2[j]) {            
            flag++;
            i++;
            j++;
        } else if(s1[i] < s2[j]) {
            i++;
        } else {
            j++; 
        }
    }
    cout << flag;
}
```

Comment: Define "are the same". There are many ways to interpret that.

Comment: Do you need to count _different_ characters that match, or all of them? If `s1` is "ss" and `s2` is "ss", is the result 1 or 2?

Comment: Your current program outputs 4, not expected 6 nor unexpected 8: [Demo](http://ideone.com/N6edoh).

Comment: According to your implementation, input strings should be sorted.

Comment: Why do you expect 6 for your sample input, when the two strings have all 8 characters in common? I can't come up with a possible interpretation of the problem statement that would result in 6 being the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All elements of s1 are present in both strings so the output will be equal to the length of s1. Here is the correct code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char s1[] = "FOOBART";
    char s2[] = "BFORATO";
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(s1)-1; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<sizeof(s2)-1; j++) {
            if (s1[i]==s2[j]) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<count<<endl;
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

solution using stl algorithms:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    const std::string s1 = "FOOBART";
    std::string s2 = "BFORATO";

    int count = 0;
    auto beg = begin(s2);
    for(auto& elm : s1)
    {
        auto x = find(beg, end(s2), elm);
        if(x != end(s2))
        {
            *x = *beg;//get rid of elment and reduce the range of search.
            ++beg;
            ++count;
        }

    }
    std::cout << count;
    return 0;
}
```